# Finding which man and woman hired first in each department

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will return both the first hire male for each department. So far I've got the following:

```
select firstnme + ' ' + lastname as Name, hiredate, workdept
from emp
where sex = 'M' and hiredate in(select min(hiredate) from emp group by workdept) 
group by workdept, hiredate, firstnme, lastname
```

This just gives me the names of Men who are the first hired in their department. If a woman was the first person hired then it doesn't return a result for that department - how do I alter the query to return the result I want for all departments?

Comment: the coding I have so far actually looks like this:                                                   select firstnme + ' ' + lastname as Name, hiredate, workdept
from emp
where hiredate in(select min(hiredate) from emp group by workdept) 
group by workdept, hiredate, firstnme, lastname

Comment: Can you provide us the table schema you are working off of?

Comment: you need to include sex in your correlated subquery.  (that sure doesn't sound strange does it?)

Comment: If a department has men and women in it -- Do you want to see both the earliest man "Adam" and earliest woman "Eve"?  or Do you only want to see "Adam" since his start date was earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by workdept, sex
                                order by hiredate) as seqnum
      from emp
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you want everyone hired on the first day.

Comment: What if two persons were hired the same day in the same department? Why not to use `DENSE_RANK`?

Comment: @lad2025 then op can use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @lad2025 Ah, well, I think that your current comment is better then

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Your point is well-taken.  I simply read more singulars in the question than plurals and used `row_number()`, but I annotated that the other functions could be used.

Answer (score 0):

i'd use a window function.. probably Rank instead of Row_Number.. but you can also join to a subquery.

```
SELECT
    e.firstname + ' ' + e.lastname AS Name,
    e.hiredate,
    e.workdept
FROM
    emp e
    JOIN (SELECT
            sex,
            workdept,
            MIN(hiredate) hiredate
          FROM
            emp
          GROUP BY
            sex,
            workdept
         ) hire ON e.sex = hire.sex
                   AND e.hiredate = hire.hiredate
                   AND e.workdept = hire.workdept
```